Does C++ guarantee a minimum string length for string literals?
In C++ I can have string literals with a custom separator, like R"str-end(...verylong...)str-end";. I was astonished when Visual Studio spit out Compiler Error C2026, "string too big, trailing characters truncated", which happens when

The string was longer than the limit of 16380 single-byte characters.

Does C++ guarantee a minimum length that strings can have?
I looked up [lex.string] in C++ N4928 but didn't find anything. If nothing is specified, I could simply write a standard compliant compiler which gives C2026 for every string. That's not the idea, I presume.
Annex B, [implimits], only has a recommendation for the concatenated length, but not for an individual string.

The bracketed number
following each quantity is recommended as the minimum for that quantity. However, these quantities are
only guidelines and do not determine compliance.
(2.16) -- Characters in a string-literal (5.13.5) (after concatenation (5.2)) [65 536].

I am not looking for string::max_size, but my imagination was that I could use such a long string in my code.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-language/maximum-string-length?view=msvc-170

Also check https://stackoverflow.com/a/19366056/2879325 - there should be something similar in the C++ spec.

Annex B (Implemenation quantities) of N4928 has "(2.16) — Characters in a string-literal (5.13.5) (after concatenation (5.2)) [65 536]".

But Annex B also says "The bracketed number following each quantity is recommended as the minimum for that quantity. However, these quantities are only guidelines and do not determine compliance." I don't know if the actual limit is standardized anywhere in the C++ spec. The C language spec guarantees support for string literals of length 4095 after concatenation.

There aren't normative requirements on implementation limits at all. There are only recommendations that you already cited. For conformance the implementation could choose any arbitrary limit. It is a quality-of-implementation issue if there are pointless small limits like this.

Not a language lawyer answer, but you’ve got a source file with 16Kb string!? Maybe I’m just old, but IDK why you would expect that to work. Put that data in a resource file.

Did you mean to ask about the maximum string length? Pretty sure the minimum is 0.

@Barry: no. I am very sure I want a minimum string length that is guaranteed to work, not a maximum one.

@Dúthomhas: why not? I created an R-string, pasted a file inside and I want that to work. What else is an R-string good for? IMHO it is inspired from Python and I can easily have a 100kB R-string there. In C#, I can have a 100 kB verbatim string. Rust can do it as well. Anyone coming from such a language can just shake his head. This is just another "OMG, how bad can even modern C++ be" moment.

My last comment is not language-lawyer safe. I just tried it experimentally in PyCharm (Python 3.12), LinqPad 5 (.NET Framework), LinqPad 8 (Core 3.1, 8.0), the Rust Playground (Rust 1.81), JavaScript (JSFiddle), Lua (OneCompiler).

The standard has no normative requirements in this area. It recommends that implementations live allow for strings up to a particular length, but it doesn't impose any requirements.
Note also that MSVC's limitation is specifically on pre-concatenated string lengths. Essentially, this is the number of bytes that the compiler will let you store between quotes.
If you want to store bulk binary data (as a string), you'll have to use something else.

If nothing is specified, I could simply write a standard compliant compiler which gives C2026 for every string.

Yes you could. And how many people would use your implementation?
The standard doesn't need to forbid malicious or useless implementations; the market will do that.

String concatenation is a great way around the character limit between quotes.

By this logic, the entire Implementation Limits annex is not really needed. But it's common in language standards to set a baseline on what is expected. There's no reason they couldn't have included one on the pre-concatenation string lengths, they just chose not to.

@MarkRansom: not really. It's a pain. I pasted my file contents into the R-String, just to figure out where and how often I need to split it. And if someone else copies the contents of the string back into a file, I'm pretty sure they will miss one of the R-String parts and they end up with an invalid file.

@ThomasWeller I have a bunch of .h files created with Python where we use string concatenation to create a single string out of an entire binary file.  The largest is 15K but I'm sure we had larger ones during development.  The Python code breaks the string into appropriate size pieces and hex-encodes everything that's not a valid string character so we don't need R-strings.  The most interesting aspect was detecting and working around accidental digraphs and trigraphs.

@MarkRansom: IMHO, it's a missed chance that C++ had. Very long R-strings work in every other language. Agreed, maybe I should use a resource file. But what about beginners? I am a teacher. Now I have 2 choices: a) explain how resource files work or b) explain string concatenation and C++ limits. It's hard to grasp for students that a 2011 C++ feature does not work as good as a C# feature from 2001 (yes, it's in C# 1.0 already). I just feel sorry for C++.

@ThomasWeller: "But what about beginners?" Why is a "beginner" making gigantic strings?

@NicolBolas: because they want to write files to disk. Or store the default config hard coded and run through the same parser if no config file was found. And for all the other reasons that more experienced programmers use large strings: mostly convenience, I guess. I often use large strings when I want to distribute an interesting problem to colleagues that they can just copy/paste into a single file, without setting up a lot of stuff.

@ThomasWeller: "because they want to write files to disk." What does writing a file to disk have to do with having a 16k string in your source files? I've written plenty of things to disks without needing that. "Or store the default config hard coded and run through the same parser if no config file was found." I guess we have very different definitions of what "beginner" tasks are.
