# Stack Smashing and using malloc

Tags: c

I'm making a program that counts the number of words contained within a file. My code works for certain test cases with files that have less than a certain amount  of words/characters...But when I test it with, let's say, a word like:

"loooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooong", (this is not random--this is an actual test case I'm required to check), it gives me this error:

```
*** stack smashing detected ***: ./wcount.out terminated
Abort (core dumped)
```

I know what the error means and that I have to implement some sort of malloc line of code to be able to allocate the right amount of memory, but I can't figure out where in my function to put it or how to do it:

```
int NumberOfWords(char* argv[1]) {
  FILE* inFile = NULL;
  char temp_word[20]; <----------------------I think this is the problem

  int num_words_in_file;
  int words_read = 0;

  inFile = fopen(argv[1], "r");

  while (!feof(inFile)) {
    fscanf(inFile, "%s", temp_word);
    words_read++;
  }
  num_words_in_file = words_read;

  printf("There are %d word(s).\n", num_words_in_file - 1);
  fclose(inFile);
  return num_words_in_file;

}
```

Comment: Not sure if you wanted to tag [tag:c++] or what, but this is completely unrelated to [tag:c#].

Comment: So you're reading a string of unknown length into 20 bytes and wondering why why are stomping on the stack? Use more than 20? Read 20 (probably 19) chars at a time. Many possible approaches.

Comment: There are several errors in the code. Not testing `inFile` after `fopen`. Please see [Why is “while ( !feof (file) )” always wrong?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feof-file-always-wrong) `char temp_word[20]` cannot hold the 247-length string you attempt to read with the unrestricted `fscanf(inFile, "%s", temp_word)` and so on.

Comment: If you are intending to count the number of words in a file, then throwing `"loooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooong"` at it is stupid. There are very few words with 20 or more characters, so increase the array length to say 100, and restrict the input length.

Comment: Re the edit: is the "actual test case" you are required to input supposed to be a valid word, or a test case that you should reject?

Comment: It should be a valid test case that should print, "There are 1 word(s)." Regardless of the length/ridiculousness of the word, it's still 1 read "word".

Comment: All I want to do is use malloc to not worry about how large a word will be and continue with the program to count the number of words

Comment: Even with malloc you need to know the length of the word BEFORE.

Answer (score 0):

As you've correctly identified by rendering your source code invalid (future tip: `/* put your arrows in comments */`), the problem is that `temp_word` only has enough room for 20 characters (one of which must be a terminal null character).

In addition, you should check the return value of `fopen`. I'll leave that as an exercise for you. I've answered this question in other questions (such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30419563/translation-limit-in-c)), but I don't think just shoving code into your face will help you.

In this case, I think it may pay to better analyse the problem you have, to see if you actually need to store *words* to count them. As we define a *word* (the kind read by `scanf("%s", ...)` as a sequence of non-whitespace characters followed by a sequence of (zero or more) whitespace characters, we can see that such a *counting* program as yours needs to follow the following procedure:

1. Read as much whitespace as possible
2. Read as much non-whitespace as possible
3. Increment the "word" counter if all was successful

You don't need to store the non-whitespace any more than you do the whitespace, because once you've read it you'll never revisit it. Thus you could write this as two loops embedded into one: one loop which reads as much whitespace as possible, another which reads non-whitespace, followed by your incrementation and then the outer loop repeats the whole lot... until `EOF` is reached...

This will be best achieved using the `%*s` directive, which tells `scanf`-related functions not to try to store the *word*. For example:

```
size_t word_count = 0;
do {
     fscanf(inFile, "%*s");
} while (!feof(inFile) && ++word_count);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are limited by the size of your array. A simple solution would be to increase the size of your array. But you are always susceptible to stack smashing if someone enters a long word.

A word is delimited by spaces.

You can simply store a counter variable initialized to zero, and a variable that records the current char that you are looking at. Every time you read in a character using `fgetc(inFile, &temp)` that is a space, you increment the counter.

Answer (score 0):

In your current code you simply want to count the words. Therefore you are not interested in the words themselves. You can suppress the assignment with the optional `*` character:

```
    fscanf(inFile, "%*s");
```